# Change Sinch SMS Verification Text

Tags: ios, sinch

I am using this brilliant product called **Sinch** for mobile number verification.

Everything works as expected and I am able to verify the mobile number in question.

I have a rather odd query. Currently the verification sms that I receive  says **"Your verification code is xxxx"**, is there a way I can modify this according to as per my needs? Lets say to **"Your 'App Name' verification Code is xxxx"**

Comment: can you mark my question as answered please?

Comment: There you go! I'm sorry Mate. I believe one of my colleagues had gotten in touch with you via mail. He had provided you with the required text and API keys. Though the text wasn't updated as of yesterday. But since this seems to be the only way of doing it I am marking your answer as correct. Many Thanks!!

Comment: hey, I am not aware of any quee mail me christian@sinch.com and I will personally look in to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can't do it your self due to that we need to verify the test before tha change. Mail support@sinch.com with you appkeys and text and we will take care of you

Comment: Do you support Arabic text for the message?
Also do you support changing "from" sender ID to be my company name in Arabic?

Comment: Arabic content yes, sender id, no